# How to toggle in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to toggle labels to change with a toggle button but I just can't figure it out. with code 1, it doesn't change to value at all, and with code 2, it changes for a split second. I can't figure out how to make it toggle and stay toggled. can anyone help me out with this

**CODE 1**

```
 bool isActive = false;
        public void OnGUI() {


            

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("insert"))
            { 
                isActive = !isActive;
            }
            
            if (isActive == true)
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "on");
            }
            else
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "off");
            }
```

[image: result of code 1] with pressing insert, it doesnt change

**CODE 2**

```
 public void OnGUI() {


            bool isActive = false;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("insert"))
            { 
                isActive = !isActive;
            }
            
            if (isActive == true)
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "on");
            }
            else
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "off");
            }
```

[image: result of code 2]

Comment: This isn't a question about the Visual Studio application, nor is it a question about the UnityScript scripting language.

Comment: I don't do Unity, but does OnGUI() get called on every frame (e.g. 60 times a second)? Perhaps you need to check how long has elapsed since you last toggled it. Code 2 can't possibly work since you're effectively writing `bool isActive = true; if (isActive == true)`. Reason: there's no persistence of `isActive` outside of the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the `GetKeyDown` from the `Update` function since the state gets reset for each frame. I suggest using `KeyCode` as well instead of string key names.

Sample

```cs
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isActive = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Insert))
        {
            isActive = !isActive;
        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isActive == true)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "on");
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), "off");
        }
    }
}
```